# Egyptian Fractions in C

Tags: java, c, algorithm, math, fractions

The ancient Egyptians only used fractions of the form `1/n` so any other fraction had to be represented as a sum of such unit fractions and, furthermore, all the unit fractions were different!

What is a good method to make any fraction an egyptian fraction (the less sums better) in C or java, what algorithm can be used, branch and bound, a*?

for example:

```
3/4 = 1/2 + 1/4

6/7 = 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/42
```

Comment: Why is this tagged "artificial-intelligence"?

Comment: More of a math / number theory question. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EgyptianFraction.html for lots of links.

Comment: @In silico why did you remove math tag, which I add?? Actually this is a mathematical  question.

Comment: What do you mean by "good method"? Easy to implement? Shortest length expansion? Quickest to execute? Something else?

Comment: any algorithm that has some features as you said, Quickest to execute is a very nice one

Comment: @Ashot Martirosyan: I didn't remove the `[math]` tag from this question which obviously has to do with math. [I'm not math-illiterate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159219/angle-measurer-in-c/4159284#4159284). I'm 100% sure I removed the `[artificial-intelligence]` flag.

Comment: @In silico: From the timestamps, I guess it was an edit clash.

Comment: @Ashot Martirosyan: According to the revisions page, I submitted my edit 1 second after you submitted your edit, so I obviously didn't see that you have already fixed the `[artificial-intelligence]` before I submitted my edit.

Comment: @In silico it's Ok, No problem :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way is the greedy algorithm.  Given the fraction `f`, find the largest Egyptian fraction `1/n` less than or equal to `f` (i.e., n = ceil(1/f)).  Then repeat for the remainder `f - 1/n`, until `f == 0`.

So for 3/4, you'd compute:

- n = ceil(4/3) = **2**; remainder = 3/4 - 1/2 = **1/4**
- n = ceil(4) = **4**; remainder = 1/4 - 1/4 = 0
- 3/4 = 1/2 + 1/4

And for 6/7:

- n = ceil(7/6) = **2**; remainder = 6/7 - 1/2 = **5/14**
- n = ceil(14/5) = **3**; remainder = 5/14 - 1/3 = **1/42**
- n = ceil(42) = **42**; remainder = 1/42 - 1/42 = 0
- 6/7 = 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/42

Answer (score 3):

**Cropped from [Egyptian Fractions](http://www.jimloy.com/egypt/fraction.htm)**

> How did I come up with these values?
>   Well, I estimated the fraction with
>   the largest unit fraction that was
>   just smaller than the given fraction.
>   I subtracted this unit fraction from
>   the given fraction. If this remainder
>   was still not a unit fraction, I
>   repeated the process, choosing the
>   largest unit fraction that is smaller
>   than this remainder. And the process
>   could be repeated over and over.
>
> Let's use 7/8 as an example. We
>   estimate 7/8 with 2/3 (the largest
>   unit fraction less than 7/8). We
>   subtract 7/8 - 2/3, which is 5/24,
>   which cannot be simplified into a unit
>   fraction. So we estimate 5/24 with 1/5
>   (the largest unit fraction less than
>   5/24). We subtract 5/24-1/5, and we
>   get 1/120, which is a unit fraction.
>   So, 7/8=2/3 + 1/5 + 1/120.

Comment: @quasiverse: It's not, but the Egyptians had special symbols for 2/3 and 3/4 instead of being required to write 1/2+1/6 or 1/2+1/4.

Comment: Taking @dano04's comment that 2/3 and 3/4 were given special treatment, the second paragraph of the explanation is puzzling to me. Why isn't 3/4 a better starting point than 2/3?  7/8 = 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 looks simpler to me than 7/8 = 1/2 + 1/6 + 1/5 + 1/120 (aka: 7/8 = 1/2 + 1/5 + 1/6 + 1/120).   One reason might be that the reference didn't recognize 3/4 as having special treatment; I'm not sure whether there are any others.

Answer (score 2):

For `a / b`, make MAX a * b.

Take the prime factors of MAX (which is the union of prime_fac(a) and prime_fac(b) and the multiples one each from those two lists) and iterate through them, starting low and going high.

Those are your possible 1/x's.

Edit: 
Oh yeah! Don't forget to take into consideration `2/3`!

Comment: And how would it work for `6/7`, where prime factors are `2`, `3` and `7`?

Comment: @Andrey Prime factors are all prime factors of 42. I shouldn't have used the word "union" in there without further clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You asked a question on a website where people usually provide code in their answers. There are no other answers with code, C and Java are not my specialty, and so here is some code in Python.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import fractions
import functools
import math


def main():
    f = fractions.Fraction(3, 4)
    e = to_egyptian_fractions(f)
    print(*e, sep=' + ')
    f = fractions.Fraction(6, 7)
    e = to_egyptian_fractions(f)
    print(*e, sep=' + ')
    f = fractions.Fraction(7654, 321)
    e = to_egyptian_fractions(f)
    print(*e, sep=' + ')


def validate(function):
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def wrapper(fraction):
        total = fractions.Fraction(0)
        for egyptian in function(fraction):
            if 1 not in {egyptian.numerator, egyptian.denominator}:
                raise AssertionError('function has failed validation')
            yield egyptian
            total += egyptian
        if total != fraction:
            raise AssertionError('function has failed validation')
    return wrapper


@validate
def to_egyptian_fractions(fraction):
    quotient = math.floor(fraction.numerator / fraction.denominator)
    if quotient:
        egyptian = fractions.Fraction(quotient, 1)
        yield egyptian
        fraction -= egyptian
    while fraction:
        quotient = math.ceil(fraction.denominator / fraction.numerator)
        egyptian = fractions.Fraction(1, quotient)
        yield egyptian
        fraction -= egyptian


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Maybe others with find this to be useful as a simple guide while writing their own implementations. The program up above handles fractions with values greater than one and produces the following output.

```
1/2 + 1/4
1/2 + 1/3 + 1/42
23 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/92 + 1/29532
```