# Most accurate way to do a combined multiply-and-divide operation in 64-bit?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, math

What is the most accurate way I can do a multiply-and-divide operation for 64-bit integers that works in both 32-bit and 64-bit programs (in Visual C++)? (In case of overflow, I need the result mod 2<sup>64</sup>.)

(I'm looking for something like [MulDiv64](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/MulDiv64.aspx), except that this one uses inline assembly, which only works in 32-bit programs.)

Obviously, casting to `double` and back is possible, but I'm wondering if there's a more accurate way that isn't too complicated. (i.e. I'm not looking for arbitrary-precision arithmetic libraries here!)

Comment: Have you considered the [long long](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458923/long-long-in-c-c) type?

Comment: @MikeNakis, the intermediate result of the multiply requires 128 bits so a `long long` doesn't work.

Comment: wh00ps, I did not realize that `long long` is only 64 bits! I thought they would have made it 128 bits!  I just looked it up. Pity. Well then your next option might be wonderful inline assembly!

Comment: Doesn't MSVC have a uint128_t in its stdint.h?

Comment: Then write this function and build it with a better compiler (off the top of my head, GCC and Clang have uint128_t), and link the resulting binary to your program.

Comment: Are you dividing by a variable? Or are you dividing by a compile-time constant?

Comment: Then that makes it a LOT harder... :( The only idea I have left is to basically implement a small arbitrary precision library... Another idea to bounce around is to use the floating-point method to get 53-bits of accuracy. Then run one iteration of Newton's Method (which uses only multiplications and additions) on 64/128-bit arithmetic.

Comment: Curious, have you tried the code in straight c++ and looking at the generated assembly with optimizations turned on?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453146/128-bit-division-intrinsic-in-visual-c

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1188939/293511

Comment: I don't know what the answer is but I know it is in Knuth's Seminumerical Algorithms.

Comment: Related: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/microsoft/VC-Language/30133426/128by64-division.aspx

Comment: @CAFxX: On Microsoft compilers, the type is called `__int128`.

Comment: @BenVoigt It isn't implemented though - even on x64: `error C4235: nonstandard extension used : '__int128' keyword not supported on this architecture`

Comment: @Mystical: What version of VC++?  I saw some references saying that newer versions have it.

Comment: Some information about `__int128` - not sure if it's still up to date, though: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/529171/implement-128-bit-type

Comment: @BenVoigt I didn't get your response cause you left out the `i` in my UN. I'm using VS2010 SP1.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I tested it and VS2010 SP1 still doesn't support it in either x86 or x64 toolchains.  Voted for the connect issue.

Comment: Just wondering, how important is the overflow case of where the result should be `mod 2^64`? I think my answer meets all your criteria (with perfect integer truncation) except for the overflow case. As of right now, I can't find a clean way to deal with the overflow case. (And actually the 64-bit `div` and `idiv` instructions will throw an exception if the quotient is >64-bits.) So there may not be a clean way to do this even with access to inline assembly.

Comment: @Mysticial: It's actually not too important for my program what happens in that case, as long as the result is otherwise predictable/sensible (e.g. saturation would be fine too)... though I would guess that other people who want this would probably want the answer to be mod 64. However, working on a 32-bit program definitely **is** important, because the numbers are all 64-bit. So while your answer is great for a 64-bit program, I can't use it because I need to use this for a 32-bit system as well.

Comment: I see, it would be much more complicated in the 32-bit case since those intrinsics are all x64. Most of them are easy to implement manually. The only tricky one is `_umul128()`, which would have to be done using the long-multiplication suggestions here.

I suppose a work-around would be to combine it with the implementation you linked to.

Comment: @Mysticial: Oh wow, good point about combining them... funny, I just tried out `MulDiv64(0x1203785013274012, 0x1cef95b58432904f, 0x53)` on both implementations, and *neither* gave back [Wolfram Alpha's](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%280x1203785013274012+*+0x1cef95b58432904f+%2F+0x53%29++mod+2%5E64) answer of `0x05DC4FD990C5C443` ... and Microsoft's Power Calculator gave back `0x647AC843C8E79298B21B29FB808EF.347` for the same thing, but without the mod... which should result in `0x298B21B29FB808EF` after truncation. I feel like I'm missing something. Ideas?

Comment: For that one, the quotient overflows 64-bits. My current answer does something unpredictable in that case. I can fix that fairly easily though. EDIT: Did you flip the order of the parameters? The answer to that is `32607500402250344521899981391005935` EDIT2: That answer is the IEEE double-precision representation of the result, not an integer.

Comment: @Mysticial: Oooooh yeah I probably flipped them. I assumed `first * second / third`... probably wasn't correct. Still kinda weird that Alpha and Power Calculator give different answers, though... EDIT: Yeah the IEEE representation kinda baffled me, not sure why they gave me back a floating-point number in its hexadecimal representation. I'll use PowerCalc then.

Comment: `first * second / third` is correct. `a * b / c` in my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Since this is tagged Visual C++ I'll give a solution that abuses MSVC-specific intrinsics.**

This example is fairly complicated. It's a highly simplified version of the same algorithm that is used by GMP and `java.math.BigInteger` for large division.

Although I have a simpler algorithm in mind, it's probably about 30x slower.

**This solution has the following constraints/behavior:**

- It requires x64. It will not compile on x86.
- The quotient is not zero.
- The quotient saturates if it overflows 64-bits.

Note that this is for the unsigned integer case. It's trivial to build a wrapper around this to make it work for signed cases as well. This example should also produce correctly truncated results.

**This code is not fully tested.** However, it has passed all the tests cases that I've thrown at it.
(Even cases that I've intentionally constructed to try to break the algorithm.)

```
#include <intrin.h>

uint64_t muldiv2(uint64_t a, uint64_t b, uint64_t c){
    //  Normalize divisor
    unsigned long shift;
    _BitScanReverse64(&shift,c);
    shift = 63 - shift;

    c <<= shift;

    //  Multiply
    a = _umul128(a,b,&b);
    if (((b << shift) >> shift) != b){
        cout << "Overflow" << endl;
        return 0xffffffffffffffff;
    }
    b = __shiftleft128(a,b,shift);
    a <<= shift;


    uint32_t div;
    uint32_t q0,q1;
    uint64_t t0,t1;

    //  1st Reduction
    div = (uint32_t)(c >> 32);
    t0 = b / div;
    if (t0 > 0xffffffff)
        t0 = 0xffffffff;
    q1 = (uint32_t)t0;
    while (1){
        t0 = _umul128(c,(uint64_t)q1 << 32,&t1);
        if (t1 < b || (t1 == b && t0 <= a))
            break;
        q1--;
//        cout << "correction 0" << endl;
    }
    b -= t1;
    if (t0 > a) b--;
    a -= t0;

    if (b > 0xffffffff){
        cout << "Overflow" << endl;
        return 0xffffffffffffffff;
    }

    //  2nd reduction
    t0 = ((b << 32) | (a >> 32)) / div;
    if (t0 > 0xffffffff)
        t0 = 0xffffffff;
    q0 = (uint32_t)t0;

    while (1){
        t0 = _umul128(c,q0,&t1);
        if (t1 < b || (t1 == b && t0 <= a))
            break;
        q0--;
//        cout << "correction 1" << endl;
    }

//    //  (a - t0) gives the modulus.
//    a -= t0;

    return ((uint64_t)q1 << 32) | q0;
}
```

Note that if you don't need a perfectly truncated result, you can remove the last loop completely. If you do this, the answer will be no more than 2 larger than the correct quotient.

**Test Cases:**

```
cout << muldiv2(4984198405165151231,6132198419878046132,9156498145135109843) << endl;
cout << muldiv2(11540173641653250113, 10150593219136339683, 13592284235543989460) << endl;
cout << muldiv2(449033535071450778, 3155170653582908051, 4945421831474875872) << endl;
cout << muldiv2(303601908757, 829267376026, 659820219978) << endl;
cout << muldiv2(449033535071450778, 829267376026, 659820219978) << endl;
cout << muldiv2(1234568, 829267376026, 1) << endl;
cout << muldiv2(6991754535226557229, 7798003721120799096, 4923601287520449332) << endl;
cout << muldiv2(9223372036854775808, 2147483648, 18446744073709551615) << endl;
cout << muldiv2(9223372032559808512, 9223372036854775807, 9223372036854775807) << endl;
cout << muldiv2(9223372032559808512, 9223372036854775807, 12) << endl;
cout << muldiv2(18446744073709551615, 18446744073709551615, 9223372036854775808) << endl;
```

**Output:**

```
3337967539561099935
8618095846487663363
286482625873293138
381569328444
564348969767547451
1023786965885666768
11073546515850664288
1073741824
9223372032559808512
Overflow
18446744073709551615
Overflow
18446744073709551615
```

Comment: Modified to saturate on overflow. Getting the full mod by `2^64` behavior on the quotient is not trivial at all since it requires 128-bit x 64-bit multiplies.

Comment: Seems to work pretty darn well, and indeed it's better than using `double`: `muldiv2(0x1203785013274012, 0x1234, 0x1238) == 0x11ff83d891999ab0`; according to the calculator, `0x1203785013274012 * 0x1234 / 0x1238 == 0x11FF83D891999AB0.F112...` so it's completely correct. Using `double` yields: `(unsigned long long)(0x1203785013274012 * (double)0x1234 / 0x1238) == 0x11ff83d891999b08` which is inaccurate. Nice; thanks a lot! :) (For 32-bit I used version from the [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/MulDiv64.aspx) site.)

Answer (score 8):

You just need 64 bits integers. There are some redundant operations but that allows to use 10 as base and step in the debugger.

```
uint64_t const base = 1ULL<<32;
uint64_t const maxdiv = (base-1)*base + (base-1);

uint64_t multdiv(uint64_t a, uint64_t b, uint64_t c)
{
    // First get the easy thing
    uint64_t res = (a/c) * b + (a%c) * (b/c);
    a %= c;
    b %= c;
    // Are we done?
    if (a == 0 || b == 0)
        return res;
    // Is it easy to compute what remain to be added?
    if (c < base)
        return res + (a*b/c);
    // Now 0 < a < c, 0 < b < c, c >= 1ULL
    // Normalize
    uint64_t norm = maxdiv/c;
    c *= norm;
    a *= norm;
    // split into 2 digits
    uint64_t ah = a / base, al = a % base;
    uint64_t bh = b / base, bl = b % base;
    uint64_t ch = c / base, cl = c % base;
    // compute the product
    uint64_t p0 = al*bl;
    uint64_t p1 = p0 / base + al*bh;
    p0 %= base;
    uint64_t p2 = p1 / base + ah*bh;
    p1 = (p1 % base) + ah * bl;
    p2 += p1 / base;
    p1 %= base;
    // p2 holds 2 digits, p1 and p0 one

    // first digit is easy, not null only in case of overflow
    uint64_t q2 = p2 / c;
    p2 = p2 % c;

    // second digit, estimate
    uint64_t q1 = p2 / ch;
    // and now adjust
    uint64_t rhat = p2 % ch;
    // the loop can be unrolled, it will be executed at most twice for
    // even bases -- three times for odd one -- due to the normalisation above
    while (q1 >= base || (rhat < base && q1*cl > rhat*base+p1)) {
        q1--;
        rhat += ch;
    }
    // subtract 
    p1 = ((p2 % base) * base + p1) - q1 * cl;
    p2 = (p2 / base * base + p1 / base) - q1 * ch;
    p1 = p1 % base + (p2 % base) * base;

    // now p1 hold 2 digits, p0 one and p2 is to be ignored
    uint64_t q0 = p1 / ch;
    rhat = p1 % ch;
    while (q0 >= base || (rhat < base && q0*cl > rhat*base+p0)) {
        q0--;
        rhat += ch;
    }
    // we don't need to do the subtraction (needed only to get the remainder,
    // in which case we have to divide it by norm)
    return res + q0 + q1 * base; // + q2 *base*base
}
```

Comment: Looking for similar approach for signed types (no unsigned types in java unfortunately). Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

This is a community wiki answer, since it's really just a bunch of pointers to other papers/references (I'm unable to post relevant code).

The multiplication of two 64-bit ints to a 128 bit result is pretty easy using a straightforward application of pencil & paper technique everyone learns in grade school.

GregS's comment is correct: Knuth covers division in "The Art of Computer Programming, Second Edition, Volume 2/Seminumerical Algorithms" at the end of Section 4.3.1 Multiple Precision Arithmetic/The Classical Algorithms (pages 255 - 265 in my copy).  It's not an easy read, at least not for someone like me who's forgotten most mathematics beyond 7th grade Algebra. Just prior, Knuth covers the multiplication side of things, too.

Some other options for ideas (these notes are for division algorithms, but most also discuss multiplication):

- Jack Crenshaw covers the Knuth division algorithms in a more readable manner in a series of articles from Embedded System Programming magazine 1997 (unfortunately, my notes don't have the exact issues). Sadly, articles from old ESP issues are not easy to find online. If you have access to a University library, maybe some back issues or a copy of the ESP CD-ROM Library is available to you.
- Thomas Rodeheffer of Microsoft research has a paper on Software Integer Division: http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/70645/tr-2008-141.pdf
- Karl Hasselström's paper on "Fast Division of Large Integers": http://www.treskal.com/kalle/exjobb/original-report.pdf or http://treskal.squarespace.com/s/masters-thesis.pdf
- Randall Hyde's "Art of Assembly Language" (http://webster.cs.ucr.edu/AoA/Windows/HTML/AoATOC.html), specifically Volume Four Section 4.2.5 (Extended Precision Division): http://webster.cs.ucr.edu/AoA/Windows/HTML/AdvancedArithmetica2.html#998729  this is in Hyde's variant of x86 assembly language, but there's also some pseudocode and enough explanation to port the algorithm to C.  It's slow, too - performing the division bit-by-bit...

Answer (score 3):

Since this is tagged Visual C++ you can use the [newly available intrinsics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56033459/995714):

- Mul: [`_mul128()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/mul128?view=vs-2019), [`_umul128()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/umul128?view=vs-2019)
- Div: [`_div128()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/div128?view=vs-2019), [`_udiv128()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/udiv128?view=vs-2019)

```
uint64_t muldiv_u64(uint64_t a, uint64_t b, uint64_t c)
{
    uint64_t highProduct;
    uint64_t lowProduct = _umul128(a, b, &highProduct);
    uint64_t remainder;
    return _udiv128(highProduct, lowProduct, c, &remainder);
}
```

If you need signed mul-div then just use the version without `u`

See also

- [How can I descale x by n/d, when x*n overflows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63091924/995714)
- [How can I multiply and divide 64-bit ints accurately?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18022544/995714)
- [How to multiply a 64 bit integer by a fraction in C++ while minimizing error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25182577/995714)
- [(a * b) / c MulDiv and dealing with overflow from intermediate multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54232987/995714)

Comment: However, this does not match the question's requirement _"In case of overflow, I need the result mod 2⁶⁴"_

Answer (score 2):

You don't need *arbitrary* precision arithmetic for that. You only need 128-bit arithmetic. I.e. you need 64*64=128 multiplication and 128/64=64 division (with proper overflow behavior). This is not that difficult to implement manually.

Comment: Is the margin here too small to write down an implementation? (jk)

Comment: The problem is that there is `128/64=64` primitive on amd64 architecture, but there is no corresponding compiler intrinsic for it. As such, without assembly, you have to build it using `64/64->64` and the result is not as efficient.

Comment: you don't _need_ arbitrary precision arithmetic, but it is pretty simple and error proof to use a library for arbitrary precision, which is very likely to perform better than any ad-hoc code you may write too, so much that I would avoid any custom code which is longer than 5-6 lines and fall back to the library.

Comment: @pqnet: Well, there are different levels of ad-hoc... The difference between fixed-precision code and arbitrary-precision code is *qualitative*, meaning that just a *regular* implementation of 128-bit arithmetic ("regular" meaning "straightforward", "no ultra-clever fast math tricks") will noticeably outperform any arbitrary-precision library. In my code I use self-implemented and quite simple 128-bit and 256-bit arithmetic support and it does easily outperform any "big-number" library we tried so far.

Comment: @AndreyT there is no "regular" implementation of division, only complex tricks like the ones shown in many of the answer here. Also, the arbitrary precision library will likely have a good performance if there is a native support for 128 bits operations

Comment: @pqnet: It depends on what you see as "regular". In my implementation I simply use classic long division we all know from school (of course, I do it in binary). And yes, in my implementation I do rely on 128-bit math support from the compiler (if available) as well as on compiler built-ins (if available).

Comment: @AndreyT but your implementation is not so simple that you could write it down in an answer here, so it may be worth thinking about using a library instead.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the COMP type (x87-based 64-bit integer type) at your disposal in VC++? I've used it occasionally in Delphi in the past when I needed 64-bit integer math. For years, it was way faster than the library-based 64-bit integer math - certainly when division was involved.

In Delphi 2007 (the latest I have installed - 32-bits), I would implement MulDiv64 like this:

```
function MulDiv64(const a1, a2, a3: int64): int64;
var
  c1: comp absolute a1;
  c2: comp absolute a2;
  c3: comp absolute a3;
  r: comp absolute result;
begin
  r := c1*c2/c3;
end;
```

(Those weird *absolute* statements layer the comp variables on top of their 64-bit integer counter parts. I would have used simple type casts except the Delphi compiler gets confused about that - probably because the Delphi language (or whatever they call it now) has no clear syntactic distinction between type casting (reinterpret) and value type conversion.)

Anyway, Delphi 2007 renders the above as follows:

```
0046129C 55               push ebp
0046129D 8BEC             mov ebp,esp
0046129F 83C4F8           add esp,-$08

004612A2 DF6D18           fild qword ptr [ebp+$18]
004612A5 DF6D10           fild qword ptr [ebp+$10]
004612A8 DEC9             fmulp st(1)
004612AA DF6D08           fild qword ptr [ebp+$08]
004612AD DEF9             fdivp st(1)
004612AF DF7DF8           fistp qword ptr [ebp-$08]
004612B2 9B               wait 

004612B3 8B45F8           mov eax,[ebp-$08]
004612B6 8B55FC           mov edx,[ebp-$04]
004612B9 59               pop ecx
004612BA 59               pop ecx
004612BB 5D               pop ebp
004612BC C21800           ret $0018
```

The following statement yields 256204778801521550, which appears to be correct.

```
writeln(MulDiv64($aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa, $555555555555555, $1000000000000000));
```

If you want to implement this as VC++ inline-assembly, it's possible that you would need to do some tweaking of the default rounding flags to accomplish the same thing, I don't know - I haven't had the need to find out - yet :)

Comment: X87 support has generally been poor in a lot of C compilers, probably because a lot of printf-related code assumes `double` and `long double` are synonymous and will break if they aren't.  It really irks me that the extended-precision FP type has gotten a bad reputation, when it's a faster type to work with than a 64-bit `double` *even on machines with no FPU*.

Comment: @supercat Are you sure 80 bit long doubles are faster than 64 bit doubles when using the SSE instructions for 64 bit? Because I'm quite sure they're not.

Comment: @PaulGroke: This answer (above) is 7+ years old by now - things have no doubt changed significantly since then.

Comment: @PaulGroke: The bad reputation of the extended-precision type goes back to a time when many machines either had an FPU that could handle it as fast as a 64-bit double or no FPU at all (which meant that they could handle it faster than a 64-bit `double`).  Hardware support for the type was effectively dropped as a consequence of that.  If extended-precision types hadn't become unpopular before SSE was invented, SSE could have been designed to support them efficiently, bearing in mind that few applications would require loading or storing large numbers of extended-precision values...

Comment: ...so the performance of vector load/store operations on such values wouldn't be overly important.  What would be useful would be to have registers that could contain e.g. either four 80-bit values and eight 40-bit values, along with instructions that would load and store in either packed/rounded form 64/32-bit forms, or padded 128/64 bit forms, with the latter being used mainly for context save/restore/spill code.

Comment: When loading or storing large numbers of values, having the type be a small power-of-two size is important.  When loading or storing a smaller number, doubling the size isn't really a problem.  And when keeping them in registers, there's nothing magical about powers of two.

Comment: @supercat Doesn't really matter why, but it's a fact that the 64 bit type is faster on modern CPUs (and that includes the ones that were current in 2012). Simply because they have more computation units for the 64 bit type than for the 80 bit type. Also it's not true that the 80 bit type was just as fast on the older CPU generations, at least not if you also count division and actually want an accurate result. (The division/sqrt precision of the x87 unit can be configured, and it's faster if you limit the precision for what's needed for the 64 bit type.)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Things actually haven't changed that much since 2012 in that regard. Also it doesn't even matter if it was true then. Even if it were, it's not true now, and hence it should be corrected.

Comment: @PaulGroke: Floating-point division has always involved trade-offs between precision and performance, but I think that on a platform with fast extended-precision multiplication and addition along with an "approximate reciprocal" function, using extended precision multiplies and additions to refine an approximate reciprocal for the divisor and then multiply by the dividend could yield a result that's within double-precision ulp faster than would be practical using double-precision math alone.

Comment: @supercat Yes, for constant divisors that would probably work. But doesn't mean that extended precision is (or better: was, on pre-SSE2 machines) _in general_ as fast as double precision.

Comment: @PaulGroke: For non-constant divisors, given an approximation of the reciprocal, each iteration of Newton's method can double the number of significant figures.  With fast extended-precision addition and multiplication hardware and a decent initial guess, computation of a reciprocal that's accurate to better than one part in 2**53 will be much faster than a double-precision division.

Comment: @supercat OK, now I understand what you meant :) Anyway, that doesn't really have to do with double precision vs. extended precision, has it?. Also there is the problem of the decent initial guess. If this was a good, exact general purpose solution, I bet someone at AMD/Intel would know how to do it in hardware/firmware. Or maybe they have already done it. Rough estimation: we may need up to 8 rounds and each round will probably be 3-5 cycles (latency, not throughput!). Which means up to 24~40 cycles. Which AFAIK is about what a double precision division takes on modern CPUs.

Comment: @PaulGroke: From what I understand, a significant number of floating-point architectures include an "approximate reciprocal" function.  Outside of weird scenarios involving denormals, a 12-bit approximation can be produced easily with a 4096x12 lookup table.  The benefit of extended-precision types is that it's often much easier to design an algorithm that produces a result that's within 256ulp of of the correct value in the type used, than one which is always within 1ulp, and rounding an extended precision value that's within 256ulp of being correct will yield a `double within 9/16ulp.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to support Windows 7 and newer, one good way is this:

```
#include <mfapi.h>
#include <assert.h>
#pragma comment( lib, "mfplat.lib" )

uint64_t mulDiv64( uint64_t a, uint64_t b, uint64_t c )
{
    assert( a <= LLONG_MAX && b <= LLONG_MAX && c <= LLONG_MAX );
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Mfapi/nf-mfapi-mfllmuldiv
    return (uint64_t)MFllMulDiv( (__int64)a, (__int64)b, (__int64)c, (__int64)c / 2 );
}
```

This method is much simpler than what’s in other answers here, it rounds the result instead of truncating, and it works on all Windows platforms including ARM.

Comment: Interesting but I doubt this matches the question's requirement _"In case of overflow, I need the result mod 2⁶⁴"_ (which can occur for low `c`).

Answer (score 1):

Below presented muldiv64.asm source for Windows-x86-64 Visual Studio. More details about compiling/testing/exceptions available in https://github.com/LF994/MulDiv64

```
include listing.inc

_TEXT   SEGMENT
  PUBLIC asmMulDiv64

asmMulDiv64 PROC
  mov  rax,rdx    ; rax <- b
  mul  rcx        ; 128 bits of rax*rcx placed into rdx+rax (a was in rcx) 
  div  r8         ; [rdx,rax] / r8: result->rax, reminder->rdx (c was in r8)
; Quotient already in rax, place here "mov rax,rdx" if you want to return remainder instead.
  ret  0          ; 0: do not remove parameters from stack
asmMulDiv64 ENDP

_TEXT   ENDS
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can chop up your 64 bit operands into 32 bit chunks (low and high part). Than do the operation on them that you want. All intermediate results will be less than 64 bit and can therefore be stored in the data types you have.

Comment: Chunking a multiply into parts is easy, but I've never seen a clean way to do divide.

Answer (score 0):

For 64-bit mode code you can implement 64*64=128 multiplication similarly to the implementation of [128/64=64:64 division here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8456388/968261).

For 32-bit code it'll be more complex because there's no CPU instruction that would do multiplication or division of such long operands in 32-bit mode and you'll have to combine several smaller multiplications into a bigger one and reimplement long division.

You may use the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7709021/968261) as a framework for building long division.

Of course, if your dividers are always less than 2<sup>32</sup> (or better yet 2<sup>16</sup>), you can do much faster division in 32-bit mode by chaining several divisions (divide the most significant 64 (or 32) bits of the dividend by the 32-bit (or 16-bit) divisor, then combine the remainder from this division with the next 64 (32) bits of the dividend and divide that by the divisor and keep doing that until you use up the entire dividend). Also, if the divisor is big but can be factored into sufficiently small numbers, dividing by its factors using this chained division will be better than the classical looping solution.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that you want to multiply `a` by `b` and then divide by `d`:

```
uint64_t LossyMulDiv64(uint64_t a, uint64_t b, uint64_t d)
{
    long double f = long double(b)/d;
    uint64_t highPart = uint64_t((a & ~0xffffffff) * f + 0.5);
    uint64_t lowPart = uint64_t((a & 0xffffffff) * f + 0.5);
    return highPart + lowPart;
}
```

This code splits the value of `a` into higher and lower 32-bit parts, then multiplies the 32-bit parts separately by 52-bit precise ratio of `b` to `d`, rounds the partial multiplications, and sums them up back to an integer.
Some precision still gets lost, but the result is more precise than just plain `return a * double(b) / d;` .

Answer (score -1):

Here's an approximation method you can use: (full precision unless a > 0x7FFFFFFF or b > 0x7FFFFFFF and c is larger than a or b)

```
constexpr int64_t muldiv(int64_t a, int64_t b, int64_t c, unsigned n = 0) {
  return (a < 0x7FFFFFFF && b < 0x7FFFFFFF) ? (a * b) / c : (n != 2) ? (c <= a) ? ((a / c) * b + muldiv(b, a % c, c, n + 1)) : muldiv(a, b, c / 2) / 2 : 0;
}
```

The modulo is used to find the loss of precision, which is then plugged back into the function. This is similar to the classic division algorithm.

2 was chosen because `(x % x) % x = x % x`.

Comment: Does this work? The first case I tested is `muldiv(4984198405165151231,6132198419878046132,9156498145135109843)` and it gives `0`. The correct answer is `3337967539561099935`.

Comment: @Mysticial Seems to choke when c is larger than a or b. I'll see if I can fix it.

Comment: Now it gives `3269073876237821221`, which is better but still not right. I assume it's still a work in progress... Though I'm having trouble deciphering how it's supposed to work. If you can get this to work I'll be very impressed that you can do it without any 64 x 64 -> 128 bit multiplies)

Comment: @Mysticial Yeah, doesn't seem possible to get full precision without more bits.