# How can I multiply and divide 64-bit ints accurately?

Tags: c, math, biginteger

I have a C function:

```
int64_t fn(int64_t a, int32_t b, int32_t c, int32_t d)
{
    /* should return (a * b * c)/d */   
}
```

It is possible for a to be near INT64_MAX, but for the final result not to overflow, for instance if b = 1, c = d = 40.  However, I am having trouble figuring out how to compute this so that I never lose data to rounding (by doing the division first) or have an intermediate result overflow.

If I had access to a large enough datatype to fit the whole product of a, b, and c, I would just do the math in that type and then truncate, but is there some way I can do this without big integers?

Comment: Depends how fast you need it.  If you're willing to do something like prime factorization you can reduce it without losing precision, but it's much slower.

Comment: Are you working on x86_64?

Comment: @Thomas: You don't have to do the full prime factorization...finding the GCD is sufficient, and much faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write `a = q*d + r` with `|r| < |d|` (I'm assuming `d != 0`, otherwise the computation is meaningless anyway). Then `(a*b*c)/d = q*b*c + (r*b*c)/d`. If `q*b*c` overflows, the entire computation would overflow anyway, so either you don't care, or you have to check for overflow. `r*b*c` might still overflow, so we again use the same method to avoid overflow,

```
int64_t q = a/d, r = a%d;
int64_t part1 = q*b*c;
int64_t q1 = (r*b)/d, r1 = (r*b)%d;
return part1 + q1*c + (r1*c)/d;
```

Comment: If you take `a==INT64_MAX-1`, `b==INT64_MAX`, `c==1`, and `d==INT64_MAX` then `a*b*c/d==INT64_MAX-1` while your procedure overflows on `r*b` since `r==INT64_MAX-1`. It is pretty easy to do `r*b` in 128 bits, even manually using two 64 bits variables - just split the numbers in high and low 32 bits parts and then use the `(rH+rL)*(bH+bL)`. However, later you still need to do the division and modulo by `d` of the 128 bits number, so in the end the problem remains...

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to see that some inputs would produce outputs that cannot be represented by the return type `int64_t`. For example, `fn(INT64_MAX, 2, 1, 1)`. However, the following approach <strike>will</strike> should allow you to return a correct answer for any combination of inputs that does in fact fit within the range of `int64_t`.

```
int64_t fn(int64_t a, int32_t b, int32_t c, int32_t d)
{
    /* find the integer and remainder portions of a/d */
    int64_t leftI = a / d;
    int64_t leftR = a % d;

    /* multiply the integer portion of the result by b and c */
    int64_t resultI = leftI * b * c;

    /* multiply the remainder portion by b */
    int64_t resultR = leftR * b;
    resultI = resultI + (resultR / d) * c;

    /* multiply the remainder portion by c */
    resultR = (resultR % d) * c;

    return resultI + (resultR / d);
}
```

Comment: This is elegant, but doesn't seem to work out for the case (23, 40, 5, 5).  Any ideas why?

Comment: @user2521200 I forgot a `*c` in there. Updated the answer to correct it.

Comment: Take a=9999, b= 0.96*MaxInt, c=1, d = MaxInt, and this will overflow at resultR=leftR*b. I was trying to use it to scale a 64-bit random into a smaller range and it won't work. It tries to multiply 9999 by ~MaxInt which obviously fails.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest finding the greatest common divisor of d with each of a, b, and c,
dividing out the common factors as you go:

```
common = gcd(a,d) // You can implement GCD using Euclid's algorithm

a=a/common
d=d/common

common = gcd(b,d)
b=b/common
d=d/common

common = gcd(c,d)
c=c/common
d=d/common
```

Then calculate `a*b*c/d` with all the common factors removed.  Euclid's GCD algorithm 
runs in logarithmic time, so this should be fairly efficient.

Comment: This is nice mathematically, but does not help if OP also wants results where the result of the division would be dropping a remainder. In terms of the "integer division operator" /, a*b*c/d has an "exact" answer even if a,b,c,d are all relatively prime, and this answer might fit in the resulting type even when the intermediary operations overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on x86_64 then the asm supports 128 bit integers:

```
int64_t fn(uint64_t a, uint64_t b, uint64_t c, uint64_t d) {

    asm (
        "mulq %1\n"          // a *= b
        "movq %%rbx, %%rdx\n"// rbx = upper 64 bit of the multiplication
        "mulq %2\n"          // multiply the lower 64 bits by c
        "push %%rax\n"       // temporarily save the lowest 64 bits on the stack
        "mov %%rcx, %%rdx\n" // rcx = upper 64 bits of the multiplication
        "movq %%rax, %%rbx\n"// 
        "mulq %2\n"          // multiply the upper 64 bits by c
        "addq %%rax, %%rcx\n"// combine the middle 64 bits
        "addcq %%rdx, $0\n"  // transfer carry tp the higest 64 bits if present
        "divq %3\n"          // divide the upper 128 (of 192) bits by d
        "mov %%rbx, %%rax\n" // rbx = result
        "pop %%rax\n"
        "divq %3\n"          // divide remainder:lower 64 bits by d
        : "+a" (a)           // assigns a to rax register as in/out
        , "+b" (b)           // assigns b to rbx register
        : "g" (c)            // assigns c to random register
        , "g" (d)            // assigns d to random register
        : "edx", "rdx"       // tells the compiler that edx/rdx will be used internally, but does not need any input
    );

    // b now holds the upper 64 bit if (a * b * c / d) > UINT64_MAX
    return a;
}
```

Please note that all input integers have to be the same length. Working length will be double the input. Works with unsigned only.

The native `div` and `mul` instructions on x86 work on double-length exactly to allow for overflows. Sadly I am unaware of a compiler intrinsic to make use of them.

Comment: The first `mulq` will produce a 128-bit output, but the second `mulq` cannot use the upper 64 bits as part of its input, as far as I know; even if it could, you could still overflow since a*b*c could take up to 192 bits. Also, the `divq` instruction will fault if the upper 64 bits are greater than or equal to the divisor.

Comment: @R.. Yeah, I was hoping to avoid those problems, but you are right. I posted a fixed and extended version, but now it's more complicated then I like it myself.

Comment: It would be simpler if you defined a macro or function to do the 64x64->128 multiplication (via asm) with output in an array, and likewise for the division, then wrote the actual logic in C.