# How to multiply a 64 bit integer by a fraction in C++ while minimizing error?

Tags: c++, multiplication, integer-overflow, integer-division

Given a 64 bit (signed) `long long` or `__int64`, how would you go about multiplying it by an arbitrary fraction while at the same time minimizing error?

Three simple sketches:

```
int64_t numerator = ...;
int64_t denominator = ...;
int64_t x = ...;

// a, lossy double conversion for large values
double fraction = static_cast<double>(numerator) / static_cast<double>(denominator);
int64_t result = x * fraction;

// b, divide first, problem if denominator value near (or even larger) x
int64_t result = x / denominator;
result *= numerator;

// c, multiply first, problem if multiplication overflows
int64_t result = x * numerator;
result /= denominator;
```

I would be fine with truncating the result to the nearest integer if `x * n / d` mathematically doesn't yield a whole number.

Comment: Use your third method with 128-bit arithmetic.

Comment: You may alternatively use a *BigInt* library and then manage the overflow manually to fit in your `int64_t`.

Comment: @jbutler483 - Title is a dup. Question body not so, I'd say.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733178/most-accurate-way-to-do-a-combined-multiply-and-divide-operation-in-64-bit

Comment: The word is `muldiv`.

Comment: Why even consider `double` when there is `long double`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improving on provided answer (this reduces overflow when `b` is big):

```
int64_t muldiv64(const int64_t a, const int64_t b, const int64_t d)
{
    /* find the integer and remainder portions of x/d */
    const int64_t diva = a / d;
    const int64_t moda = a % d;
    const int64_t divb = b / d;
    const int64_t modb = b % d;

    return diva * b + moda * divb + moda * modb / d;
}
```

there is no need to write weird code to avoid using the modulus operation: the compiler can do the substitution and you can have a more readable code.

**edit:**
Any more complicated code is probably not worth to look into. If more precision is needed probably the good idea is moving to 128 bit arithmetic or use arbitrary precision integer libraries (see http://sourceforge.net/projects/cpp-bigint/)

Comment: Note that there are the same issues than the previous answer for cases where `a < d`, `b < d` but `a * d` overflows. It just solves issues of other answer when `b >= d`.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, i didn't mean for it to be the best possibility, just an improvement over the previous solutions. If a more accurate solution is needed probably it is a good idea to use an arbitrary precision integer library such as http://sourceforge.net/projects/cpp-bigint/

Answer (score 4):

You may use the following:

```
const int64_t q = x / denominator;
const int64_t r = x - q * denominator;
// x = q * denominator + r;
const int64_t result = q * numerator + ((r * numerator) / denominator);
```

Note: you may get both the quotient and the remainder at once with `std::div` family.

Note: As pointed by  Sander De Dycker, there are still problems when
`r * numerator / denominator` overflows
and with the special case `x = INT64_MIN, denominator = -1` where `x / denominator` overflows.

Comment: better still make it an inline function `int64_t muldiv64(int64_t x, int64_t numerator, int64_t denominator)`

Comment: Interesting. What'd you say: Better `r = x%d` or your `r = x - q * d`?

Comment: Are the semantics of `%` standardised for negative numbers yet?

Comment: @Ben - [Seems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594508/modulo-operator-with-negative-values) C++11 has defined it.

Comment: @MartinBa: It should be identical. (Maybe one is more efficient than the other).

Comment: how about input like `x = INT64_MAX - 1`, `numerator = 2`, `denominator = INT64_MAX` ? Your code will set `result` to `0`, while it should be `1`.

Comment: or better yet, input like `x = INT64_MIN`, `numerator = -1`, `denominator = -1` will generate a core dump.

Answer (score 2):

More or less copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18022952/321013), this seems to make the most sense to me:

```
int64_t muldiv64(const int64_t x, const int64_t n, const int64_t d)
{
    /* find the integer and remainder portions of x/d */
    const int64_t div = x / d;
    const int64_t mod = x % d;

    return div * n + (mod * n) / d;
}
```

Comment: Tested it on `int8_t` for simplicity, it overflows on `x=3, n=86, d=87`. So I believe you can find 64-bit equivalence.