# How can I multiply 64 bit operands and get 128 bit result portably?

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, x86-64

For x64 I can use this:

```
 {
   uint64_t hi, lo;
  // hi,lo = 64bit x 64bit multiply of c[0] and b[0]

   __asm__("mulq %3\n\t"
    : "=d" (hi),
  "=a" (lo)
    : "%a" (c[0]),
  "rm" (b[0])
    : "cc" );

   a[0] += hi;
   a[1] += lo;
 }
```

But I'd like to perform the same calculation portably. For instance to work on x86.

Comment: What are the types of c[0] and b[0] ?  Why not just multiply two uint64_t types?

Comment: What is the problem? and what is the question?

Comment: mulq is the 64 bit instruction that is the problem and c&b is uint64_t

Comment: write it in C++ for correctness. **MEASURE** if it's too slow. if it is, check the generated 32-bit assembly.

Comment: there is no any generated 32 bit assembly and its c not c++ why you navigate me to other ways than writing a basic solution

Comment: If it is C rather than C++, why did you tag the question C++? Very hard to understand why you would want to use asm to perform trivial multiplication. I also cannot understand your question. I don't know what you are asking.

Comment: deleted c++ tag and just want to make it without using inline asm thats all and i want be able to compile it for 32 bit machines mulq is 64 bit instruction

Comment: OK, you want a pure C 64 bit multiplication that produces a 128 bit result? Does this do what you need? http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/618570/UInt-Multiplication-Squaring

Comment: Or maybe this is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776073/efficient-multiply-divide-of-two-128-bit-integers-on-x86-no-64-bit

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Kudos on the cleanup!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As I understand the question, you want a portable pure C implementation of 64 bit multiplication, with output to a 128 bit value, stored in two 64 bit values. In which case this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/618570/UInt-Multiplication-Squaring) purports to have what you need. That code is written for C++. It doesn't take much to turn it into C code:

```
void mult64to128(uint64_t op1, uint64_t op2, uint64_t *hi, uint64_t *lo)
{
    uint64_t u1 = (op1 & 0xffffffff);
    uint64_t v1 = (op2 & 0xffffffff);
    uint64_t t = (u1 * v1);
    uint64_t w3 = (t & 0xffffffff);
    uint64_t k = (t >> 32);

    op1 >>= 32;
    t = (op1 * v1) + k;
    k = (t & 0xffffffff);
    uint64_t w1 = (t >> 32);

    op2 >>= 32;
    t = (u1 * op2) + k;
    k = (t >> 32);

    *hi = (op1 * op2) + w1 + k;
    *lo = (t << 32) + w3;
}
```

Comment: This uses 4 multiplications. You could reduce it to 3 by using Karatsuba's trick. Not sure how much it would increase speed.

Comment: @ThomasAhle: It wouldn't; modern CPUs typically have pipelined multipliers, so you can get 1 result per 1 or 2 clocks.  Having to do a lot more adds is worse, especially when you  have to work around C's lack of an add-with-carry primitive operation so 128-bit additions cost even more than they would in asm.

Comment: You mean it'd be slow because we'd have to worry about overflow when adding two 64 bit numbers? Though sometimes you know the numbers are less than 2^60, say, so you can split in 30 bit chucks and have room to spare for carries.

Comment: @ThomasAhle: didn't see your reply since you didn't @ notify me.  It'd be slower because you have significantly more total operations.  Multiply isn't that slow compared to addition, and often a more important consideration is total number of micro-uops.  (Usually one per instruction).  Especially with out-of-order exec being able to overlap execution with surrounding code that hopefully doesn't bottleneck on multiply throughput.  If actually compiling this C for a 64-bit CPU, the asm for just this will have a lot of non-multiply instructions to split up 64-bit integer regs to 32-bit halves...

Comment: Working with 30-bit or 60-bit chunks can be a good technique if you're limited to pure C.  Although probably not needed here since none of these 64-bit additions need to generate carry-out or take carry-in.

Answer (score 12):

Since you have `gcc` as a tag, note that you can just use `gcc`'s 128-bit integer type:

```
typedef unsigned __int128 uint128_t;
// ...
uint64_t x, y;
// ...
uint128_t result = (uint128_t)x * y;
uint64_t lo = result;
uint64_t hi = result >> 64;
```

Comment: [Getting the high part of 64 bit integer multiplication](//stackoverflow.com/a/50958815) shows an ifdeffed version of that with MSVC's `_umulh` intrinsic.  MSVC also has a `_umul128`.

Comment: Non-standard extensions are not "portable", and "portable" is even in the title of the question.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted solution isn't really the best solution, in my opinion.

- It is confusing to read.
- It has some funky carry handling.
- It doesn't take advantage of the fact that 64-bit arithmetic may be available.
- It displeases ARMv6, the God of Absolutely Ridiculous Multiplies. Whoever uses [`UMAAL`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Cihcihgg.html) shall not lag but have eternal 64-bit to 128-bit multiplies in 4 instructions.

Joking aside, it is much better to optimize for ARMv6 than any other platform because it will have the most benefit. x86 needs a complicated routine and it would be a dead end optimization.

The best way I have found (and used in [xxHash3](https://github.com/Cyan4973/xxHash/blob/8e5fdcbe70687573265b7154515567ee7ca0645c/xxh3.h#L292)) is this, which takes advantage of multiple implementations using macros:

It is a *tiny* bit slower than mult64to128 on x86 (by 1-2 instructions), but a lot faster on ARMv6.

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#  include <intrin.h>
#endif

/* Prevents a partial vectorization from GCC. */
#if defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__clang__) && defined(__i386__)
  __attribute__((__target__("no-sse")))
#endif
static uint64_t multiply64to128(uint64_t lhs, uint64_t rhs, uint64_t *high)
{
    /*
     * GCC and Clang usually provide __uint128_t on 64-bit targets,
     * although Clang also defines it on WASM despite having to use
     * builtins for most purposes - including multiplication.
     */
#if defined(__SIZEOF_INT128__) && !defined(__wasm__)
    __uint128_t product = (__uint128_t)lhs * (__uint128_t)rhs;
    *high = (uint64_t)(product >> 64);
    return (uint64_t)(product & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF);

    /* Use the _umul128 intrinsic on MSVC x64 to hint for mulq. */
#elif defined(_MSC_VER) && defined(_M_IX64)
#   pragma intrinsic(_umul128)
    /* This intentionally has the same signature. */
    return _umul128(lhs, rhs, high);

#else
    /*
     * Fast yet simple grade school multiply that avoids
     * 64-bit carries with the properties of multiplying by 11
     * and takes advantage of UMAAL on ARMv6 to only need 4
     * calculations.
     */

    /* First calculate all of the cross products. */
    uint64_t lo_lo = (lhs & 0xFFFFFFFF) * (rhs & 0xFFFFFFFF);
    uint64_t hi_lo = (lhs >> 32)        * (rhs & 0xFFFFFFFF);
    uint64_t lo_hi = (lhs & 0xFFFFFFFF) * (rhs >> 32);
    uint64_t hi_hi = (lhs >> 32)        * (rhs >> 32);

    /* Now add the products together. These will never overflow. */
    uint64_t cross = (lo_lo >> 32) + (hi_lo & 0xFFFFFFFF) + lo_hi;
    uint64_t upper = (hi_lo >> 32) + (cross >> 32)        + hi_hi;

    *high = upper;
    return (cross << 32) | (lo_lo & 0xFFFFFFFF);
#endif /* portable */
}
```

On ARMv6, you can't get much better than this, at least on Clang:

```
multiply64to128:
        push    {r4, r5, r11, lr}
        umull   r12, r5, r2, r0
        umull   r2, r4, r2, r1
        umaal   r2, r5, r3, r0
        umaal   r4, r5, r3, r1
        ldr     r0, [sp, #16]
        mov     r1, r2
        strd    r4, r5, [r0]
        mov     r0, r12
        pop     {r4, r5, r11, pc}
```

The accepted solution generates a bunch of `adds` and `adc`, as well as an extra `umull` in Clang due to an instcombine bug.

I further explain the portable method in the link I posted.

Comment: `__attribute__((__target__("no-sse")))` will probably stop it from inlining into functions with different target options, which might defeat constant propagation as well as adding call/ret overhead (especially in the nasty stack-args calling convention most 32-bit code uses).  But that's only for 32-bit x86 so it's probably not going to hurt many use-cases.

Comment: That is true. However, from testing on a Sandy Bridge, the shuffles completely bottleneck the algorithm.

Comment: Have you reported the missed-optimization bug to gcc's bugzilla?  I was just pointing out that the workaround isn't perfect, but IDK if there's a way to do anything cheaper without using `-fno-tree-vectorize` for the whole file.  Your attribute is might well be the best choice if `-O3 -march=native` shoots itself in the foot that badly.