# C unsigned long long overflow on another in array

Tags: c, c99, integer-overflow, unsigned-long-long-int

Let's say I've an array of `unsigned long long`, is there a way to put the overflow in the next `ull`? I want exact number so double aren't an option.
For now this is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long d[2] = {1,0}, n[2] = {0,0}; // denominator, numerator
unsigned long long nd = 1;

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    while(1){

        if(nd+2 < nd) // next denominator greater than 2^64-1
            return 0;
        // n = n*nd + d
        n[0] = n[0] * nd + d[0];
        // n[1] += *overflow    <------
        n[1] = n[1] * nd + d[1];
        d[0] *= nd;
        // d[1] += *overflow    <------
        d[1] *= nd;
        printf("current denominator: %llu -> 4*%llu/%llu\n", nd, n, d);
        nd += 2; //increment next denominator
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no simple solution unless your compiler has an integer type wider than `unsigned long long`

Comment: If you only need it to work for the case `unsigned long long` = 64-bit, then (a) use `uint64_t` instead, and (b) [see this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095741/how-can-i-multiply-64-bit-operands-and-get-128-bit-result-portably)