# Karatsuba Integer Multiplication failing with segmentation fault

Tags: c++, karatsuba

As I run the program, it crashes with segmentation fault. Also, when I debug the code in codeblocks IDE, I am unable to debug it as well. The program crashes even before debugging begins. I am not able to understand the problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Method to make strings of equal length
int makeEqualLength(string& fnum,string& snum){
    int l1 = fnum.length();
    int l2 = snum.length();
    if(l1>l2){
        int d = l1-l2;
        while(d>0){
            snum  = '0' + snum;
            d--;
        }
        return l1;
    }
    else if(l2>l1){
        int d = l2-l1;
        while(d>0){
            fnum  = '0' + fnum;
            d--;
        }
        return l2;
    }
    else
        return l1;
}

int singleDigitMultiplication(string& fnum,string& snum){
    return ((fnum[0] -'0')*(snum[0] -'0'));
}

string addStrings(string& s1,string& s2){
  int length = makeEqualLength(s1,s2);
  int carry = 0;
  string result;
  for(int i=length-1;i>=0;i--){
    int fd = s1[i]-'0';
    int sd = s2[i]-'0';
    int sum = (fd+sd+carry)%10+'0';
    carry = (fd+sd+carry)/10;
    result = (char)sum + result;
  }
  result = (char)carry + result;
  return result;
}

long int multiplyByKaratsubaMethod(string fnum,string snum){

    int length = makeEqualLength(fnum,snum);
    if(length==0) return 0;
    if(length==1) return singleDigitMultiplication(fnum,snum);

    int fh = length/2;
    int sh = length - fh;

    string Xl = fnum.substr(0,fh);
    string Xr = fnum.substr(fh,sh);
    string Yl = snum.substr(0,fh);
    string Yr = snum.substr(fh,sh);

    long int P1 = multiplyByKaratsubaMethod(Xl,Yl);
    long int P3 = multiplyByKaratsubaMethod(Xr,Yr);
    long int P2 = multiplyByKaratsubaMethod(addStrings(Xl,Xr),addStrings(Yl,Yr)) - P1-P3;

    return (P1*pow(10,length) + P2*pow(10,length/2) + P3);
}


int main()
{
    string firstNum = "62";
    string secondNum = "465";
    long int result = multiplyByKaratsubaMethod(firstNum,secondNum);
    cout << result << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: At least observe the calls by adding `cerr << "(" << fnum << "," << snum << ")" << endl;` at the beginning of the function, and you will see the problem (infinite recursion at some point).

Comment: @RK21 I don't really believe that the program crashs before `main()` is entered. Neither could I see any code which may be suspicuous for this, nor could I verify this when I debugged it in Visual Studio. Please consider the recommendation of Jean-Baptiste Yunès and/or debug your code in single step. Btw. due to debugging, I found a serious issue in `addStrings()`. After fixing this, I noticed a stack overflow. This means, termination of recursion does not work (or at least recursion consumes too much stack). I'm just looking for the reason of this...

Comment: @Scheff... you are right. The program does not crash before calling main. It produces some values for P1 and P2, and after some time terminates with segmentation fault.

Comment: @Scheff, can you please suggest what code changes you made in addStrings method

Answer (score 1):

There are three serious issues in your code:

1. `result = (char)carry + result;` does not work.
   The carry has a value between `0` (0 * 0) and `8` (9 * 9). It has to be converted to the corresponding ASCII value:
   `result = (char)(carry + '0') + result;`.
2. This leads to the next issue: The carry is even inserted if it is `0`. There is an `if` statement missing:
   `if (carry/* != 0*/) result = (char)(carry + '0') + result;`.
3. After fixing the first two issues and testing again, the stack overflow still occurs. So, I compared your algorithm with another I found by google:
   [Divide and Conquer | Set 4 (Karatsuba algorithm for fast multiplication)](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/divide-and-conquer-set-2-karatsuba-algorithm-for-fast-multiplication/)
   (and possibly was your origin because it's looking very similar). Without digging deeper, I fixed what looked like a simple transfer mistake:
   `return P1 * pow(10, 2 * sh) + P2 * pow(10, sh) + P3;`
   (I replaced `length` by `2 * sh` and `length/2` by `sh` like I saw it in the googled code.) This became obvious for me seeing in the debugger that length can have odd values so that `sh` and `length/2` are distinct values.

Afterwards, your program became working.

I changed the `main()` function to test it a little bit harder:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string intToStr(int i)
{
  string text;
  do {
    text.insert(0, 1, i % 10 + '0');
    i /= 10;
  } while (i);
  return text;
}

// Method to make strings of equal length
int makeEqualLength(string &fnum, string &snum)
{
  int l1 = (int)fnum.length();
  int l2 = (int)snum.length();
  return l1 < l2
    ? (fnum.insert(0, l2 - l1, '0'), l2)
    : (snum.insert(0, l1 - l2, '0'), l1);
}

int singleDigitMultiplication(const string& fnum, const string& snum)
{
  return ((fnum[0] - '0') * (snum[0] - '0'));
}

string addStrings(string& s1, string& s2)
{
  int length = makeEqualLength(s1, s2);
  int carry = 0;
  string result;
  for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    int fd = s1[i] - '0';
    int sd = s2[i] - '0';
    int sum = (fd + sd + carry) % 10 + '0';
    carry = (fd + sd + carry) / 10;
    result.insert(0, 1, (char)sum);
  }
  if (carry) result.insert(0, 1, (char)(carry + '0'));
  return result;
}

long int multiplyByKaratsubaMethod(string fnum, string snum)
{
  int length = makeEqualLength(fnum, snum);
  if (length == 0) return 0;
  if (length == 1) return singleDigitMultiplication(fnum, snum);

  int fh = length / 2;
  int sh = length - fh;

  string Xl = fnum.substr(0, fh);
  string Xr = fnum.substr(fh, sh);
  string Yl = snum.substr(0, fh);
  string Yr = snum.substr(fh, sh);

  long int P1 = multiplyByKaratsubaMethod(Xl, Yl);
  long int P3 = multiplyByKaratsubaMethod(Xr, Yr);
  long int P2
    = multiplyByKaratsubaMethod(addStrings(Xl, Xr), addStrings(Yl, Yr))
    - P1 - P3;
  return P1 * pow(10, 2 * sh) + P2 * pow(10, sh) + P3;
}

int main()
{
  int nErrors = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i += 3) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j += 3) {
      long int result
        = multiplyByKaratsubaMethod(intToStr(i), intToStr(j));
      bool ok = result == i * j;
      cout << i << " * " << j << " = " << result
        << (ok ? " OK." : " ERROR!") << endl;
      nErrors += !ok;
    }
  }
  cout << nErrors << " error(s)." << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Notes about changes I've made:

1. Concerning `std` library: Please, don't mix headers with ".h" and without. Every header of `std` library is available in "non-suffix-flavor". (The header with ".h" are either C header or old-fashioned.) Headers of C library have been adapted to C++. They have the old name with prefix "c" and without suffix ".h".
   Thus, I replaced `#include <math.h>` by `#include <cmath>`.
2. I couldn't resist to make `makeEqualLength()` a little bit shorter.
3. Please, note, that a lot of methods in `std` use `std::size_t` instead of `int` or `unsigned`. `std::size_t` has appropriate width to do array subscript and pointer arithmetic i.e it has "machine word width". I believed a long time that `int` and `unsigned` should have "machine word width" also and didn't care about `size_t`. When we changed in Visual Studio from x86 (32 bits) to x64 (64 bits), I learnt the hard way that I had been very wrong: `std::size_t` is 64 bits now but `int` and `unsigned` are still 32 bits. (MS VC++ is not an exception. Other compiler vendors (but not all) do it the same way.)
   I inserted some C type casts to remove the warnings from compiler output. Such casts to remove warnings (regardless you use C casts or better the C++ casts) should always be used with care and should be understood as confirmation: Dear compiler. I see you have concerns but I (believe to) know and assure you that it should work fine.
4. I'm not sure about your intention to use `long int` in some places. (Probably, you transferred this code from original source without caring about.) As your surely know, the actual size of all `int` types may differ to match best performance of the target platform. I'm working on a Intel-PC with Windows 10, using Visual Studio. `sizeof (int) == sizeof (long int)` (32 bits). This is independent whether I compile x86 code (32 bits) or x64 code (64 bits). The same is true for gcc (on cygwin in my case) as well as on any Intel-PC with Linux (AFAIK). For a granted larger type than `int` you have to choose `long long int`.

I did the sample session in cygwin on Windows 10 (64 bit):

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -o karatsuba karatsuba.cc 

$ ./karatsuba
0 * 0 = 0 OK.
0 * 3 = 0 OK.
0 * 6 = 0 OK.
```

etc. etc.

```
999 * 993 = 992007 OK.
999 * 996 = 995004 OK.
999 * 999 = 998001 OK.
0 error(s).

$
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. The code works, but can you please elaborate on the third point as I am finding it difficult to find a connection.

Comment: Also, how can I make it work for multiplying 64 digit numbers

Comment: Sorry, this you have to develop by yourself. I would use `std::vector` to store integers with arbitrary precision. Then I would change the algorithm to work on these `std::vector` instead of `std::string`. Character conversion would be obsolete. In this case, the shifting would be done by simply moving vector elements instead of `pow()` or `<<`. You may imagine the `uint64` values like the digits in your current algorithm. Consider that `operator * (uint64, uint64)` has to return `uint128`. May be it's better to try first with `uint32`...

Comment: You may notice also this: [How can I multiply 64 bit operands and get 128 bit result portably?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095741/how-can-i-multiply-64-bit-operands-and-get-128-bit-result-portably). To use `uint32` might be faster, because you can cast them to `uint64`, multiply them simply with the `operator *` and split the return into stored result and carry using bit operators.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your 1st comment completely. I just added additional explanation.