# Can I access the two 64-bit registers in __uint128_t separately?

Tags: c, assembly, cpu-registers, int128

Consider the code below. We know that a `__uint128_t` variable is stored in 2 64-bit registers (Assume x64 processor). Requirement is to store the first 64 bits in one unsigned long variable and the next 64 bits in another unsigned long variable.

```
__uint128_t a = SOMEVALUE;
unsigned long b = a&0xffffffffffffffff;
unsigned long c = a>>64;
```

Here, *b* stores the first 64 bits and *c* the next 64 bits. Is there any other, simpler way to access the 2 registers separately instead of performing `&` and `>>` operations? I ask this because for my project, this section of code will be executed for like a trillion+ times. So it's better to verify this doubt first.

Anything with assembly code I can fool around with?

Comment: Have you considered trying a `union`?

Comment: That long constant would be clearer as `~0UL`, I think.

Comment: @TobySpeight, `unsigned long` and `~0UL` are not unambiguously 64-bit.  Better to use `uint64_t` here.

Comment: @chux, I absolutely agree, of course.  I was just going with the (possibly misguided) "requirement" of the question.  Why we'd want to store 64 bits in a variable of uncertain size is a mystery to me.

Answer (score 10):

What you have written is probably best, although truncation by casting is easier to read than the long constant.  As a rule of thumb, if you write code that's obvious and clear, that's usually easiest for your compiler to see your intent and optimise appropriately.

On [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/GoTEf5x35), I supplied this function:

```
#include <stdint.h>

void decompose(__uint128_t num, uint64_t *a, uint64_t *b) {
    *a = (uint64_t)(num >> 64);
    *b = (uint64_t)num;
}
```

When compiled for x64 with `gcc -O3`, it produces exactly the code you want:

```
decompose:
        mov     QWORD PTR [rdx], rsi
        mov     QWORD PTR [rcx], rdi
        ret
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Not just MSVC.  *Any* mainstream compiler targeting Windows x64 has to use 32-bit `unsigned long` to be ABI-compatible with existing DLLs unless they provide alternate headers, which is impossible for every 3rd-party library.  (Although to be fair, apparently the default for Windows GCC is that `long double` is 10-byte, vs. MSVC making it 8-byte, so GCC isn't strictly ABI-compatible with MSVC.  But `unsigned long` is a vastly more widely used type than `long double`, especially across ABI boundaries (function args and structs))

Comment: @PeterCordes Very true again :-)  I just realized that MSVC doesn't have a 128 bit integer type. At least I couldn't find it. It has 128 bit types for simd operations though.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Oh right :P  I'm not aware of MSVC having a 128-bit type.  It has a `_umul128` intrinsic for 64x64 => 128-bit multiplication ([How can I multiply 64 bit operands and get 128 bit result portably?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25095741)), and I think intrinsics for ADC, but I'm not sure if they're implemented efficiently.

Comment: @PeterCordes I guess in C23 one can hope for `unsigned _BitInt(128)` to work in MSVC. [clang supports it already](https://godbolt.org/z/MrGcx8MTr)

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Or right, I was going to mention `_BitInt(128)` in my answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Re “C guarantees modulo-reduction from wider *integral* types to narrower”: Only for unsigned destination types. For signed destination types, the conversion is implementation-defined.

Comment: @chux that's simply because I compiled without any of the usual warnings.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 7):

Shift/mask or a union are the way to go.  Especially if you just want to read the parts of an `__int128`, bit-manipulation is clear and will reliably compile efficiently.

**If you were replacing the upper or lower 64 bits, a `union`** would probably make it easier for the compiler to see that than bitwise mask / shift / OR. I wouldn't be surprised if both ways compile efficiently, but a `union` is probably good for human readability.

Note that ordering of the halves in a union will dependend on endianness, where bit-shifts don't.

---

I'd recommend **`uint64_t` or `unsigned long long`** instead of `unsigned long`, since Windows x64 uses 32-bit `long`.  Most other 64-bit ABIs use LP64 ABIs, but another case of 32-bit `long` is ILP32 ABIs for 64-bit CPUs, like AArch64 ILP32 and the x32 ABI.  `sizeof(void*) = 4` but `__int128` is still supported.

---

**I'd use a cast to truncate `__int128` to 64-bit**, instead of having to type the right number of `f`s in `0xffffffffffffffff`.  To me, **`(uint64_t)a`** follows Toby's guideline of "obvious and clear" even better.  Making the cast explicit instead of just by assigning to a narrower variable is good for human readers.  C guarantees modulo-reduction from wider integral types to narrower unsigned types, which means bitwise truncation from source types that are unsigned or 2's complement signed.  (Signed integers in GCC are [always 2's complement](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html).)

**`a>>64` is totally fine**.  Even for signed `__int128`, an arithmetic right shift and then assignment to a 64-bit type would discard the high 64 sign bits which might be all-ones or all-zeros, and GCC will still optimize that.

```
#include <stdint.h>
uint64_t foo_signed (__int128 num) {
    return (num >> 64) + (uint64_t)num;
    // Intentionally sloppy in the abstract machine to see what happens:
    // (u64)num is promoted back to 128-bit for + (with zero-extension because it's unsigned)
    // then the + result truncated to uint64_t for return.
    // GCC still avoids actually generating the high half of the signed shift result.
}

uint64_t foo_unsigned (unsigned __int128 num) {
    return (num >> 64) + (uint64_t)num;
}
```

Both of these compile to `lea   rax, [rdi + rsi]` / `ret` for x86-64.  ([**Godbolt**](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:13,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:13,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:13,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:13),source:%27%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0Auint64_t+foo_signed+(__int128+num)+%7B%0A++++return+(num+%3E%3E+64)+%2B+(uint64_t)num%3B%0A++++//+Intentionally+sloppy+in+the+abstract+machine+to+see+what+happens:%0A++++//+(u64)num+is+promoted+back+to+128-bit+for+%2B+(with+zero-extension+because+it!%27s+unsigned)%0A++++//+then+the+%2B+result+truncated+to+uint64_t+for+return.%0A++++//+GCC+still+avoids+actually+generating+the+high+half+of+the+signed+shift+result.%0A%7D%0A%0Auint64_t+foo_unsigned+(unsigned+__int128+num)+%7B%0A++++return+(num+%3E%3E+64)+%2B+(uint64_t)num%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:49.354207436399214,l:%274%27,m:100.00000000000001,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cclang1600,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-Wall%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:12,endLineNumber:6,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:5,selectionStartColumn:12,selectionStartLineNumber:6,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:5),source:1,wantOptInfo:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+clang+16.0.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:48.58849385604658,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cg132,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-Wall%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,wantOptInfo:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50.64579256360078,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)).

---

#### Type name for 128-bit integers

In modern GNU C, [the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html) currently only mentions (`unsigned`) `__int128`, not `__uint128_t`.

AFAIK, it's not wrong to keep using legacy `__uint128_t`; no reason for GCC devs to want to remove that name for the same type.  See [Is there a 128 bit integer in gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088282/is-there-a-128-bit-integer-in-gcc) - `__int128` has been around since GCC4.6, which is plenty old at this point.  But unless you care about ancient GCC versions, I'd recommend `unsigned __int128` for new code, like in my example above.

In ISO C23, `unsigned _BitInt(128)` will be standardized so you might prefer that.  But last I checked, only clang supported it (but not limited to 64-bit targets the way `__int128` / `__uint128_t` are).

### In new code, probably best to use a typedef

This lets you change to portable `_BitInt` as needed, and save typing.

```
#ifdef  defined(__SIZEOF_INT128__)
typedef  unsigned __int128   u128;
  // or __uint128_t for compat with even older GCC which doesn't define __SIZEOF_INT128__
#elif   ??? // feature-test macro for this C23 feature?
typedef  unsigned _BitInt(128)  u128;
#else
#error   no 128-bit integer type available
#endif

// then use   u128  in later code.
```

**You could write helper-functions or macros** if you find the shifting and/or casting is adding noise to your code.

```
static inline uint64_t hi64(u128 a) { return a >> 64; }
static inline uint64_t lo64(u128 a) { return (uint64_t)a; }
```

Then you can simply use `hi64(x)` and/or `lo64(x)`.

Comment: @Knm: Did you leave out an operator, like `a*b` vs. `a * (__uint128_t)`?  I like to put the cast ahead of the second operand in binary operations, to remind readers that it (in the abstract machine) it applies *before* the binary operator, so the other side gets promoted as well, rather than the truncated result.  (Casting has higher precedence than `*` or `+` so `(__uint128_t)a * b` is equivalent, but the other way saves readers some mental effort to verify that.)

Answer (score 0):

Variables are not stored in registers. They are stored in memory and processed in registers.

The C language supplies the `union` construct to map data in several ways, like

```
union MyUnion
{
    __uint128_t a;
    unsigned long long b[2];
} u;
```

Now you can refer to `u.a`, `u.b[0]` and `u.b[1]` at will, and the compiler is deemed to produce efficient code for the given processor.

---

Note that your construction with a mask and a shift will never be implemented as such, because processors cannot handle 128 data in a single go. Instead, your `a` will always be processed as two 64 bits numbers. In fact, the masking and the shift will never be performed.

Comment: *Variables are not stored in registers.* True in the C abstract machine, but the "as-if" rule allows optimizing variables into registers entirely in some cases, like the examples in Toby's and my answers (where an `__int128` function arg is passed in a pair of registers, and the function never stores it to memory.)  The question is tagged [assembly], so clearly they're concerned about cases where the compiler already has a value in a pair of registers.  I hope they realize that no asm instructions are needed for the splitting, and that the question is just how to express it to the compiler.

Comment: I thought the question was about optimization ("execute trillions of times..."), and was trying to *avoid* confusing them.

Comment: Some data never gets stored in memory at all.  e.g. a `__int128` return value from a function (in RDX:RAX) could get split up into separate C variables for the halves without ever being stored and reloaded.  This costs zero asm instructions.  (If you then assign those C variables to things that do get stored in memory, was it the original __int128 data getting stored after all?  Debating semantics isn't helpful here, what does matter is looking at the asm for a loop you actually care about.)

Comment: @YvesDaoust No that's not what your answer says at all.

Comment: Note that the union is less portable than the code in the question, because the ordering of high and low parts is processor-dependent.

Comment: Note that while accessing members at will in C is fine, it is undefined behavior to read from a different member than what was stored in C++.

Comment: @orlp: Yes, worth mentioning in general to avoid learning non-portable tricks.  But many C++ compilers do define the behaviour of union type-punning.  Including in the GNU dialect of C++, the same one that provides the `__uint128_t` extension this code also requires.  See [Unions and type-punning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25664848) / https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Type-punning